# Drop down or input implementation in a R Script

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, rstudio, messagebox

I am still fairly new to writing code, especially in R and I am trying to find simple ways to expedite the process of running my code.

If this is my data

```
    Month    X       Y        Z
    Jan     0.73    0.15    0.57
    Feb     0.69    0.35    0.97
    April   0.62    0.72    0.25
    Jan     1.00    0.80    0.60
    Oct     0.49    0.03    0.09
    Feb     0.46    0.09    0.99
    Aug     0.29    0.35    0.66
    Mar     0.64    0.46    0.66
    Dec     0.29    0.67    0.38
    Dec     0.12    0.82    0.35
    Jan     1.00    0.84    0.23
    Mar     0.64    0.83    0.30
```

Is it possible to create a code for my script that creates a message or input or drop down list box, which can help filter the data based on a column. For example, I would like to create a new data frame that only has the information for the month "Jan" and have it filtered through an drop down list as the code runs.

Thank you

Comment: One of the benefits (not drawbacks) of R is that it does away with time consuming drop downs in favour of much faster scripting. As you get more and more scripting practice you'll come see these advantages.

Comment: Whether or not for the simple task you are describing a GUI is necessary is your call, but you can do that for example with gWidgets - a bit of learning curve, though.

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown menus are unfortunately not optimal in R. Also i recommend the package `data.table` for sorting and filtering.

```
library(data.table)
Data <- data.table(Data)
```

To filter out only "Jan"

```
New.Data <- Data[Month=="Jan"]
```

To sort by lets say `X`

```
New.Data[order(as.numeric(X))]
```

If you provide more detail about what kinds of sorting and filtering you want to do i might be able to provide a more thorough answer.